# Jquery starts to corrupt

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm trying to loop through a series of images and text when an object is hovered over.  However, frequently the animation starts to corrupt running 2 'loops' every 600ms.  Plus at this point moving the mouse off the object fails to trigger the clearinterval.  I can't quite see where it's going wrong and am not sure if what I'm doing here is the best use of jquery.

The full page is here: https://dotdotdotcreative.studio/randomgrid12.html.  The object disciplineController is the pink dot in the TL corner.

The code seems to work but if you hover on and off a few times it will start to corrupt.

```
var patternNumber=1

var patternRotation = function () {

  $(disciplineFront).css("background-image", "var(--pattern" + patternNumber +")");
  $(disciplineFront).css("background-color", "var(--white)");
  $("h3").remove();
  $(disciplineText).append("<h3>" + disciplineArray[patternNumber] + "</h3>");
  if(patternNumber<12){
    patternNumber++;
  }else{
    patternNumber=1
  };
  console.log(patternNumber)
};

var patternRotationStop = function () {
  $("h3").remove();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(disciplineController).hover(function(){
    timer = setInterval(patternRotation, 1000);
  }, function(){
  patternRotationStop();
  clearInterval(timer);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `timer` at the global scope.

It was "declared" on assignation in the first hover handler (mouseenter event)... So limited to the scope of that function.

In the second hover handler (mouseleave event), `timer` was undefined. Therefore, the interval didn't clear.

If you wonder why there was no error... `clearInterval(undefined)` does not throw an error... And that is very good because the cases where it is useful to make sure an interval is cleared even before it exist are numerous.

```
var patternNumber=1

var patternRotation = function () {

  $(disciplineFront).css("background-image", "var(--pattern" + patternNumber +")");
  $(disciplineFront).css("background-color", "var(--white)");
  $("h3").remove();
  $(disciplineText).append("<h3>" + disciplineArray[patternNumber] + "</h3>");
  if(patternNumber<12){
    patternNumber++;
  }else{
    patternNumber=1
  };
  console.log(patternNumber)
};

var patternRotationStop = function () {
  $("h3").remove();
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  var timer;  // Declare at global scope

  $(disciplineController).hover(
    function(){
      timer = setInterval(patternRotation, 1000);
    },
    function(){
      patternRotationStop();
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.  I did try to define at global level.  Still encountered problems but I might not have done it correctly.  Anyway answer seemed to be a combination of what are probably good practices! Defined timer as null at global level as instructed (I think!) and instead of constantly adding in h3 text and removing every instance of it from the html I called the h3 by an id class and updated the html each time.  Seems to work well now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that ended up working up correctly.

```
var patternNumber = 1;//we start the patterns at 1
var timer = null;//define timer at a global level

    
var patternRotation = function () {
     $(disciplineFront).css("background-image", "var(--pattern" + patternNumber +")");//assign the pattern at the front.  var patternNumber is global so the animation will pick-up where the user left off.
     $(disciplineText).html(disciplineArray[patternNumber]);//this updates the <h3> with id "discipline text" with the corresponding array number.
     
    if(patternNumber<12){patternNumber++;//this ensures that when the pattern number reaches 12, it reverts back to 1 allowing it to keep looping if necessary
                        }else{
    patternNumber=1};
};


$(document).ready(function(){//this controls the hover
  $(disciplineController).hover(function(ev){
    timer = setInterval( patternRotation, 1000);//the number is in milliseconds and can be changed accordingly for speed.  It sets an interval going and will need clearing later if we don't want it to continue indefinitely in the background.
}, function(ev){
   clearInterval(timer);//the interval is cleared.
       $(disciplineText).html(disciplineArray[0]);//<h3> reverts back to what looks like a switched off state.  It is actually showing "" which is item 0 in the array. 
});
});
```